# Android: weird FP value when geting backtrace in SIGPROF's signal handler

Tags: android, profiling, arm, backtrace

I am doing a profiling on an android app, and want to get the backtrace in every SIGPROF's signal handler, but the ARM's reigster FP is weird which aren't the origin purpose that store a Frame Pointer and can do backtrace. the -fno-omit-frame-pointer gcc flag have been set.
the FP's value is like:

```
I/PROFILING(29341): 0 : pc=0x5c6263a8, sp=0xbeb69e90, fp=0x4, lr=0x5c626540,
I/PROFILING(29341): 1 : pc=0x5c846288, sp=0xbeb6a018, fp=0x3, lr=0x5c8589e8,
I/PROFILING(29341): 2 : pc=0x5edfef90, sp=0x609ff32c, fp=0x609ff33c, lr=0x5dc38b9c,
I/PROFILING(29341): 3 : pc=0x5da09030, sp=0x609ff340, fp=0x609ff3f4, lr=0x5da09064, 
I/PROFILING(29341): 4 : pc=0x400adb64, sp=0xbeb69d40, fp=0x4, lr=0x400c8d79,
I/PROFILING(29341): 5 : pc=0x5c6263a0, sp=0xbeb69e90, fp=0x4, lr=0x5c626540,
```

the FP value in line 3 and 4 seems correctly, but others are weird, anyone know why the FP's value is these ?

Comment: The flag `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` will not apply to shared libraries (and startup code) called from your program.  Can you give approximate locations of the `PC` values?  I think that */proc/PID/maps* or something might work from a shell.

Comment: @artless noise I have found why the FP is weird here, because the FP register have been treated as an normal register in the binary code generated by myself's JIT, which can't be affected by GCC's flag. but thanks for your help.